# mkfs + xfs + what is the right mkfs cli in order to create xfs file-system on huge disk

Tags: hard-drive, xfs, hadoop, kafka, mkfs

We need to create `xfs` file-system on  `kafka` disk

The special thing about `kafka` disk is the disk size

`kafka` disk have `20TB` size in our case

I not sure about the following `mkfs` , but I need advice to understand if the following cli , is good enough to create `xfs` file system on huge disk ( `kafka` machine )

```
 DISK=sdb
 mkfs.xfs -L kafka  /dev/$DISK -f
```

**kafka best practice**

*FileSystem Selection
Kafka uses regular files on disk, and such it has no hard dependency on a specific file system.
We recommend EXT4 or XFS. Recent improvements to the XFS file system have shown it to have the better performance characteristics for Kafka’s workload without any compromise in stability.
Note: Do not use mounted shared drives and any network file systems. In our experience Kafka is known to have index failures on such file systems. Kafka uses MemoryMapped files to store the offset index which has known issues on a network file systems.*

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with `hadoop` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `mkfs.xfs` defaults should be sufficient.

XFS has been tested on volumes hundreds of TiB in size for years.

[Kafka's XFS notes](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#xfs) state that

> The XFS filesystem has a significant amount of auto-tuning in place,
>   so it does not require any change in the default settings, either at
>   filesystem creation time or at mount.

(Docs then proceed to discuss `largio` and `nobarrier` but dismiss them as unnecessary, so ignore those.)

As always, test your workload. Probably not easy to do synthetic testing up to the load level of production. At least monitor your I/O performance.

Comment: I'd just add, that `nobarrier` mount option should be used only with cap/battery backed storage so you can be sure, that in case of sudden power failure, all disk content is synced later.